# Extract Recent Activity data from Codechef Userid

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract Recent Activity data for a user(i.e the latest submission time of a user), it is for my college project.
I tried it with BeautifulSoup in python, using it on a random user page,

Code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.codechef.com/users/peeyushy95')
page = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
f1=open('./testfile.txt', 'w+')
f1.write(soup.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

I am getting all the text fom the page But for 'RECENT ACTIVITY' only heading is written without table entries.
Can someone help me to extract the date and time of latest submission by the user?

Comment: 'Recent Activity' table is loaded from javascript. You have to some library like [dryscape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) to scrape data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Selenium Web Scraper to wait for some predefined time(say 5 seconds) after opening the webpage, and then scraped the page. I am posting main part of the code for selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
baseURL="http://www.codechef.com/users/peeyushy95"
browser.get(baseURL)
time.sleep(5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
L=str(soup)
f_out=open("/home/adi/experi/data_up.txt","w")
f_out.write(L)
f_out.close()
```